# C#, PerformanceCounter spits out an error that makes zero sense

Tags: c#

Literally all I want to do is initialize these for later use but I get a weird error which I can't find any information about online.

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
PerformanceCounter ramCounter;
```

The error is (searching the error code brings up something completely unrelated:

```
Error CS1069, The type name 'PerformanceCounter' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Diagnostics'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
```

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter/ ?

Comment: Please add the dependecy using Nugget

Comment: oh my god thank you so much, i've never had to install a package before so i was just kinda confused :p

Comment: @Lilyexe where did you get the code?

Answer (score -1):

PerformanceCounter Class is in Namespace:System.Diagnostics

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question—and, indeed, this is the entire _reason_ the OP asked the question in the first place. The error is saying it _wasn’t_ found in the namespace, so without explaining why that is—as others did and answered in the comments—this doesn’t even begin to answer the question.